# Error of edit value in SQL Workbench

Tags: database, mysql-workbench

In SQL workbench I tried to edit value of tables in existing database created by other person .It is giving an error ERROR 1064: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
SQL Statement:
How can I fix it please help me.

Comment: Editing works on the computer of a person that made it.But it is not working on my computer

Comment: If you have a syntax error then post the SQL code so we can review it.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l9sgotdtcuidqi5/Screenshot%202014-07-22%2010.32.31.png